# Facebook SDK 3.1 login error

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

When i login FB appear error message!!
error log:
FBConditionalLog: FBSession: a permission request for read permissions contains unexpected publish or manage permissions

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", @"user_photos", @"email", nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
```

How can add @"publish_actions" permissions not error message??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions instead of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];

[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) { /* handle success + failure in block */ }];
```

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/